# Swift - A function is only returning nil after appending key values from a dict?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, null

New to Swift.  Have some understanding of classes.  I have a `getSomething()` function that is supposed to return an array of key values (not the value itself, but only their keys) appended from a dict.  However, my function is only returning `nil`

```
public class MyClass {
            private var somethingA : String
            private var somethingB : String
            private var somethingC : Int

            // A dictionary
            // For example, if I add a fruit, color and price
            // ["Apple":["red":5]]
            private var complexes:[String:[String:Int]] = [String:[String:Int]]();

            init() {
                 self.somethingA = "";
                 self.somethingB = "";
                 self.somethingC = 0;
                 self.complexes = [somethingA:[somethingB:somethingC]];

            }

            // Adds a string to the dict complexes
            // For example, ["Apple] = ["", 0]
            public func addSomething(somethingAA : String) {

                 self.somethingA = somethingAA;
                 self.complexes[somethingAA] = [self.somethingB : self.somethingC];
            }

            // Adds a whole entry to the dict complexes
            // For example, ["Apple"] = ["red": 5]
            public func addComplex(somethingAA:  String, complex:(somethingBB:  String,  somethingCC:  Int)) {

                self.somethingA = somethingAA
                self.somethingB = complex.somethingBB
                self.somethingC = complex.somethingCC

                complexes[somethingAA] = [complex.somethingBB: complex.somethingCC]
            }

            // My Problem:  only returns nil
            public func getSometing() -> [String]?{

                 var myArray:[String]? = nil;

                 let keys = Array(complexes.keys);

                 for key in keys { myArray?.append(key); } // This may be the line of code that isn't properly working

                 return myArray;
            }    
        }
```

My testing file:

```
 var sampleObject:MyClass;
 sampleObject = MyClass();

 sampleObject.addSomething(somethingAA:  "Apple");
 sampleObject.addSomething(somethingAA:  "Orange");

 print(sampleObject.getSomething());
```

My `getSomething()` function only prints `nil` meaning that it's not appending the proper `keys` into `myArray`

Not exactly sure why.  Haven't really worked or familiar with `nils` since this is my first few days with Swift but I have worked with `nulls` in Java and C#.  Are `nils` equivalent to `nulls`?

The correct output that I want should be returning like:

```
["Apple", "Orange"] // not necessarily in order
```

Comment: You haven't initialised myArray in getSometing.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your `getSomething` method:

```
// this is nil, there is no object in myArray, because you initialise it to nil
var myArray:[String]? = nil;

let keys = Array(complexes.keys);

for key in keys { myArray?.append(key); } // since myArray is nil, this does nothing

// and you return nil
return myArray;
```

So either initialise the array properly:

```
var myArray:[String]? = [] // this will create new empty array
```

Or do it even simpler:

```
public func getSomething() -> [String]?{
    return Array(complexes.keys)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialised the array. So this is how it should be :

```
public func getSometing() -> [String]?{
   var myArray = [String]();
   let keys = Array(complexes.keys);
   for key in keys { myArray?.append(key); } // This may be the line of code that isn't properly working
   return myArray;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **getSometing()** function should be like this,

```
public func getSometing() -> [String]?{
   var myArray:[String] = [];
   let keys = Array(complexes.keys);
   for key in keys { myArray.append(key);}
   return myArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your are not yet instantiated myArray. Try

```
var myArray:[String]? = [String]();
```